# How to get raw tx in hex format by not fetching API from provider?

Tags: bitcore, bitcoinjs

I've looking for some solution to encode raw transaction in hex format by programmatically without fetching data from any blockchain provider. Are there any way to do this?

Comment: What is the source format (you'd like to go from X to hex, what's X)?

Comment: @sr-gi The source format is raw tx convert to hex format, For an example by fetching from API (https://testnet.blockchain.info/rawtx/4c8827bac9a78836fc90124a1d61d5fd38fca1cf606c6c7d2de19ed9a5aef276?format=hex)

Comment: I may be missing something. Your source format is already hex.